# Flutter multiple inheritance and naming conflicts

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following class definition:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:honeywell_scanner/honeywell_scanner.dart' as hw;
import 'package:wh_pick_app/common_widgets/overlay_notification.dart';

class Scanner extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<String>>
    implements hw.ScannerCallBack {
  hw.HoneywellScanner honeywellScanner = hw.HoneywellScanner();

@override
  String? onError(Exception error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
```

I get an error:

'onError' is inherited as a getter (from 'StateNotifier') and also a method (from 'ScannerCallBack').
Try adjusting the supertypes of this class to remove the inconsistency.

Both are libraries that I can't change the naming. How do I prevent the naming conflicts on 'onError'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

you can this

```
class Renaver extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<String>> {
  String? onError1 => super.onError();
}
class Scanner extends Renaver 
    implements hw.ScannerCallBack {
  hw.HoneywellScanner honeywellScanner = hw.HoneywellScanner();

// this ScannerCallBack.onError
@override
  String? onError(Exception error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
// this StateNotifier<AsyncValue<String>>.onError
@override
String? onError1(){
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite what I was hoping for, but helpful nonetheless.